# Bulk Insert using QueryCommand object

Tags: c#, sql-server, c#-4.0, bulkinsert

Is there any tutorial available on how to use QueryCommand to bulk insert in database. Here is the code which i am using right now:

```
QueryCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();            
try
{
    foreach (MyObj obj in list)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO " + MY_TABLE + " (name, type) VALUES (?,?)";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = obj.name != null ? obj.name : DBNull.Value.ToString();
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@type", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = obj.type != null ? obj.type.ToString() : DBNull.Value.ToString();

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Is this the correct way of doing this?
Does it fire separate query for every iteration?

Comment: With this way, your code seems fine to me. Just a tip, since you get your table name as an input, you need to supply strong validation or use a white list that contains valid table names before you put it your sql query. Also looks like your `MY_TABLE` doesn't change in your every iteration, you don't need to assign `CommandText` property everytime. Just assing it _before_ your `foreach` and clear your parameters on every iteration (as you did).

Comment: i am writing cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); in every iteration , does it fire insert query on database on each iteration , or it collects all the information and then fire insert query ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can Use `SqlBulkCopy`

here's a simple example of SqlBulkCopy code:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;

DataTable table = new DataTable("States");
// construct DataTable
table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("id_state", typeof(int))); 
table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("state_name", typeof(string)));

// note: if "id_state" is defined as an identity column in your DB,
// row values for that column will be ignored during the bulk copy
table.Rows.Add("1", "Atlanta");
table.Rows.Add("2", "Chicago");
table.Rows.Add("3", "Springfield");

using(SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connectionString))
{
  bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 600; // in seconds
  bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "state";
  bulkCopy.WriteToServer(table);
}
```

Comment: Somani, Read this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25457/Multiple-Ways-to-do-Multiple-Inserts

Comment: I was looking for QueryCommand method , what is mentioned there is specifically for oracle